# Azure AD B2C samlple code for .NET 4.5

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

Does Azure AD B2C only works with  .NET core?

I need a sample web app in MVC with .NET 4.5 for Azure AD B2C, without using .Net core and OWIN.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Azure AD B2C only works with .NET core?

No. Azure Active Directory B2C is a highly available, global, identity management service for consumer-facing applications that scales to hundreds of millions of identities. It can be easily integrated across mobile and web platforms.
It supports industry standard protocols such as OpenID Connect makes identity management possible on a variety of platforms, such as .NET and Node.js.

Here is a [code sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet) using the .Net OWIN OpenId connect component and you can follow the helpful article about it [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/). If you doesn’t want to use the OWIN component, you need to complete the [OpenId connect](http://openid.net/connect/) protocol in the apps yourself.